# Sort arraylist by ignoring the - character in the beginnig if present

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I want to sort an arraylist containing many lines

i want to ignore the   **' - '**

**if it is the first letter of that line**

**INPUT**

-bbb

a-aaa

-ddd

b-ddd

c-ccc

**output**

**should be  (as u can see it should be sorted on first character(a b c d )**

a-aaa

-bbb

c-ccc

-ddd

e-eee

**here is the code i have**

```
Collections.sort(arrList, new Comparator<String>() {

@Override
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    if (o1.startsWith("-") && o2.startsWith("-")) {
        return compare(o1.substring(1), o2.substring(1));
    }

    if (o1.startsWith("-")) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (o2.startsWith("-")) {
        return -1;
    }

    return o1.compareTo(o2);
}
```

});

Comment: In your description you use `-` but your code uses `|` - how is that supposed to work?

Comment: you also immediatly make one lexographicly bigger than the other just if it starts with `|`, but never care for the lexographicly values afterwards. Your Question asked how to ignore them, your code tells us different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final String o1s;
final String o2s;

if (o1.startsWith("|")) {
    o1s = o1.substring(1);
} else {
    o1s = o1;
}

if (o2.startsWith("|")) {
    o2s = o2.substring(1);
} else {
    o2s = o2;
}

return o1s.compareTo(o2s);
```

or, shorter but less readable

```
int o1offset = o1.startsWith("|") ? 1 : 0;
int o2offset = o2.startsWith("|") ? 1 : 0;

return o1.substring(o1offset).compareTo(o2.substring(o2offset));
```

Comment: is nice to be proud of an incorrect answer just because get accepted... Correcting the `|` symbol by `- ` to help future users would be more useful (and fast) than post this silly comment.... BTW: downvote is mine and is still waiting for your edit to be removed...

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You use `|` in the comparator and not `-`.</strike>

Your comparation is not correct, you cannot ignore `o2` if `o1` starts with `-`:

```
if (o1.startsWith("-")) {
    return 1;
}
```

This will ignore many results....

---

**To compare correctly you must follow this behaviour**: if the `String` starts with a `-` then get 2nd character (position 1) else take first character (position 0). As long as you cannot `compareTo` primitive types, `substring` of a single character will be more useful.

Do this for each String separately and `compareTo` the results.

---

Knowing this you can implement your comparator like (*there are other reduced and oneliners answers, but in order OP can better understand i will be basic*):

```
Collections.sort(arrList, new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        String s1 = "", s2 = "";

        // check first string and choose 
        //candidate character to compare
        if (o1.startsWith("-")) 
            s1 = o1.substring(1);
        else 
            s1 = o1.substring(0);

        // check second string and choose 
        // candidate character to compare
        if (o2.startsWith("-")) 
            s2 = o2.substring(1);
        else 
            s2 = o2.substring(0);

        // compare both choosen characters        
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
});
```

**Main for test:**

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("-bbb");
list.add("a-aaa");
list.add("-ddd");
list.add("b-ddd");
list.add("c-ccc");
```

**Output:**

```
a-aaa
b-ddd
-bbb
c-ccc
-ddd
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, there is no need for so much work. Just compare both values whilst using regex. The problem you initialy had is, you never ignored them when they did start with `-`, you just made one lexograhpicly greater than the other if it did start with a `-`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> testList = new ArrayList<>();
    testList.add("-bbb");
    testList.add("a-aaa");
    testList.add("-ddd");
    testList.add("b-ddd");
    testList.add("c-ccc");
    Collections.sort(testList, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            // This removes leading - from the input and ignores them
            // At the moment it removes one ore more -, if it should just be one
            // remove the +
            return o1.replaceAll("^-+", "").compareTo(o2.replaceAll("^-+", ""));
        }
    });
    for(String s : testList) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

O/P

```
a-aaa
b-ddd
-bbb
c-ccc
-ddd
```

Comment: @JordiCastilla oh yeah, just wrote random values in there, and swapped them for the values used by OP in the question, but didn´t change the `.add` input. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic for your requirement

```
public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
        if(str1.startsWith("-")){
            if(str2.startsWith("-")){
                str1 = str1.substring(1);
                str2 = str2.substring(1);

                return str1.compareTo(str2);
            }else{
                str1 = str1.substring(1);
                return str1.compareTo(str2);
            }
        } else if(str2.startsWith("-")){
            if(str1.startsWith("-")){
                str1 = str1.substring(1);
                str2 = str2.substring(1);

                return str1.compareTo(str2);
            }else{
                str2 = str2.substring(1);
                return str1.compareTo(str2);
            }
        }else{
            return str1.compareTo(str2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is ridiculously overcomplicated.